# Web.py Checkbox Returns an array made into a string...?

Tags: python, python-2.7, checkbox, web.py, checkboxlist

So I was using web.py and user.input() to handle a series of string'ed values in checkboxes.

I had the following code:

index.html

```
<form action="/checkboxposter" method="post">
    <div>
            PNG: <input type="checkbox" name="extensions" value="png" />
            Jpeg: <input type="checkbox" name="extensions" value="jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

checkboxposter.py

```
class checkboxposter:
        def POST(self):
                user_data = web.input(extensions = [])
                testofpies = user_data.extensions
                finalthing = ""
                for i in testofpies:
                        finalthing = finalthing + i

                return finalthing
```

Using the example found on the web.py site: http://webpy.org/cookbook/input

However, what would be put out would be the following:

```
[u&#39;png&#39;, &#39;jpg&#39;]
```

And if I returned finalthing[0] it would simply return [

So it's returning an array bizarrely formatted as an html-encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

I did end up solving it, but what I had to do was change

```
user_data = web.input(extensions = [])
```

to

```
user_data = web.input(extensions = [''])
```